# twitter bootstrap 2 modal boxes on same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have two modal boxes on same page whose content will also be loaded by partial once the main page loads. Ids are different for those modals. but wen I open one modal and open second one, Am getting 1st modal's content in second one. Do we need any configuration for this?

Comment: I think you can utilize this - http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap itself doesn't support this. You'll need extra custom code:

> ### [Overlapping modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.